# Does powerline adapter need a landline(phone) to connect to the internet?

Tags: powerline-networking

Do I need a landline to connect to the internet while using the power-line adapter?

To me is sounds logic, if a network communicate over electrical wires and send/receive the signals via a modem to my PC or ... , then I don't really need a landline.

Am I right? Or maybe totally wrong.

Comment: Powerline adapters are for routing LAN traffic only, using the structure's AC lines to communicate to the sister adapter for extending a LAN connection in a convenient way... Internet service requires a connection from the ISP's service line to the cable or DSL modem in the form of Fiber, shielded RG6, RJ11, or WiFi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Powerline only extends your existing network, doesn't create it.

So **yes**, you need some kind of existing network to be able to use powerline.

Comment: Thank you, it's possible if the modem communicate directly with transmission towers nearby ? then do I still need a powerline in this scenario ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand correctly your question. What type of modem, and how would it communicate with towers? Mobile data? Powerline?

Answer (score 2):

This sounds about right.
The typical "power line adapters" that I've seen are for local-site networking.  In other words, they communicate to other equipment using the same electrical system in the house.  It is essentially an alternative to Wi-Fi.

Note that I have heard some bad things about "power line adapters", such as houses having half of the outlets ("every other one" in a room) on one circuit and half of the others.  So, a "power line adapter" plugged into one outlet would only communicate to a "power line adapter" plugged into a supported outlet (on the same circuit), and not a "power line adapter" in any of the outlets that we're supported.  (But if both "power line adapters" were moved to the other circuit, that could work too.)

Also, I heard they were lower quality; really not working well, and so really not nearly as nice as new, modern, strong Wi-Fi if that could work..  I heard that mostly years ago, and I have since seen them advertised offering some higher speeds.  I suspect they got a bit better by now.  It still probably would not be my first choice if there were alternatives (Ethernet or Wi-Fi) unless maybe I found some for a relatively inexpensive price, or if I had enough of a budget to experiment with an option that was less likely to work as nicely.  (Actually, I think they've often been a bit pricier than some other connectivity options, so finding them for a rather inexpensive price might not be the most likely scenario.)

So then, you would still need some sort of Internet connection.  Landline dial-up phones are typically considered obsolete, although perhaps some areas in the world still use them.  Newer styles of Internet connections, including a "DSL modem" from a phone company, or other alternatives, can be used.  Something would need to be used.

I have heard of the concept of using the main electrical lines that come from the power company.  As I recall, what I read is that such a technology didn't seem very feasible because those lines carried a lot more electrical power downstream (to your house).  So that is not something that became very widespread (if it actually got implemented at all).

Comment: I'm pretty sure your last paragraph is very wrong - As power line technology works at high frequencies and ac voltage is in hertz (not even kHz) range the voltage is not an issue. Also, at least where I live, almost all power metres report back telemetry on at least a 30 minute basis over the power lines. I suspect the issues are more ones of distance and interittent harmonic distortion caused by things like motors.